# DB2 EXISTS TRIGGER

Tags: sql, database, triggers, db2

I use DB2 and writing a trigger count version works but I can't convert it to exists version. I will use exists version because of performance  reasons.  It is a insert after trigger.

it works

```
   IF  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table where field=NEW.field ) = 0 THEN
    ---------
   END IF;--
```

it doesn't work

```
   IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table where field=NEW.field )  THEN
    ---------------------
    END IF;--
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TRY THIS: ,AS

> BEGIN ATOMIC
>   IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table where field=NEW.field)
>       THEN
>     INSERT INTO ABC.table1 ("field1") VALUES (1100200); --> HERE IS A DUMMY INSERT I USED TO EXPLAIN 
>   END IF;
>   END;

this syntax to run this code

> db2 -td@ -f mysql.db2

You need to tell DB2 about the terminator you used !!

AND

--#SET TERMINATOR $ 
This will ser the terminator to $
To change the terminator in the CLP on the fly, the following syntax will set it back:
--#SET TERMINATOR

Comment: Thanks for answer but your solution is same as mine.